# Active X User Control COM/COM+ Communication

Tags: com, activex

Alright, well I wanted a system of communication between my webpage and a web service. I don't understand much about writing a web service and a problem I had was the fact that the web service itself would not have a user interface where I could view the processes. Then I thought about making an "ActiveX control that will show a simple user interface and accept input from a web page". So if I made an Active X control in VB.NET that had a textbox and the active x control read and responded to certain text submitted to the textbox on it from my website's form, would I have to have the web page with the active x user control open in another browser in order for it to accept a form submission from my website and respond?

Also second question: if multiple people used the form on my web site and submitted text to the active x control for it to read and respond based on how I coded it to respond to certain text, would it be able to handle multiple requests at once like a web service?

Is it just better to learn how to create a web service?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to do what your browser does not allow your script to do (like accessing local resources that the browser does not expose via the script engine), I suggest you stay on web programming and use AJAX to talk to a web service you wrote. ActiveX has limited browser support and needs extra effort to obtain other computer's trust.